# How to validate form fields such as city, zipcode in address form

Tags: magento2, customer-address, form-validation

I have done form validation as follows

```
<form class="form-address-edit"
  action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
  method="post"
  id="form-validate"
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>

  <fieldset class="fieldset required">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>   

    <div class="field city required">
        <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="city"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>"
                   id="city" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':4,'maxlength':50 }">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field zip required">
        <label class="label" for="zip">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="postcode"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>"
                   id="zip" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':6}"
                   class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit"
                class="action save primary"
                data-action="save-address"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above form works only for the `required` fields. But validations like `minlength` and `maxlength` `validate-digits` are not working.

Answer (score 0):

**replace your code with below code and try**

```
<form class="form-address-edit"
  action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
  method="post"
  id="form-validate"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <fieldset class="fieldset required">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>   

    <div class="field city required">
        <label class="label" for="city"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="city"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                   class="input-text <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>"
                   id="city" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':4,'maxlength':50 }">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field zip required">
        <label class="label" for="zip">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text"
                   name="postcode"
                   value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Zip/Postal Code')) ?>"
                   id="zip" data-validate="{'required':true,'minlength':6,'maxlength':6}"
                   class="input-text validate-zip-international <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode')) ?>">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <button type="submit"
                class="action save primary"
                data-action="save-address"
                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a class="action back" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**I hope it help..!!**

Comment: this didn't work for me